# Pattern help: Multiple-level generic inheritance in C#

Tags: c#, .net, generics, inheritance, design-patterns

I have a multiple-level class hierarchy similar to the example below:

```
                  Model                                      Dto
                 /    \                                     /  \
     CompanyModels    User Model, etc..           CompanyDto   UserDto, etc..
     /         \                                  /        \
PeopleModel  OfficeModel                     PeopleDto   OfficeDto
```

All "Company Models" share the same properties (Name, address, etc...) and the child models "People", "Office", etc... add additional properties.

In the "Model" base class, I have the following method, intended to strip the models down to only what is necessary to pass across the wire:

```
public virtual T AsDto<T>() where T : Dto, new()
{
     var dto = new T();

     dto.CreatedDate = this.CreatedDate;
     dto.CreatedUserID = this.CreatedUserID; //etc..

     return dto;
}
```

I cannot, for the life of me, figure out the best pattern to allow the "CompanyModel" to handle the assignment of properties shared by both the "PeopleModel" and "OfficeModel".

Currently I have the below set up, which I am fairly certain will not work:

```
public class CompanyModel : Model
{
     public override CompanyDto AsDto<T>()
     {
          CompanyDto c = base.AsDto<CompanyDto>();
          c.CompanyName = this.CompanyName; //etc...
          return c;
     }
}

public class PeopleModel : CompanyModel
{
     public override PeopleDto AsDto<T>()
     {
          PeopleDto p = base.AsDto<PeopleDto>() as PeopleDto; //will return null
          p.FirstName = this.FirstName;
          p.LastName = this.LastName; //etc...
          return p;
     }
}
```

Please help me figure out what the correct pattern to accomplish this is as currently I think I have just been staring at this too long...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Model
{
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public int CreatedUserID { get; set; }

    public virtual Dto AsDto()
    {
        return FillDto(new Dto());
    }

    protected Dto FillDto(Dto dto)
    {
        dto.CreatedDate = this.CreatedDate;
        dto.CreatedUserID = this.CreatedUserID; //etc..
        return dto;
    }
}


public class CompanyModel : Model
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    public override Dto AsDto()
    {
        return FillDto(new CompanyDto());
    }

    protected CompanyDto FillDto(CompanyDto dto)
    {
        base.FillDto(dto);
        dto.CompanyName = this.CompanyName;
        return dto;
    }
}

public class PeopleModel : CompanyModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public override Dto AsDto()
    {
        return FillDto(new PeopleDto());
    }

    protected PeopleDto FillDto(PeopleDto dto)
    {
        base.FillDto(dto);
        dto.FirstName = this.FirstName;
        dto.LastName = this.LastName; //etc...
        return dto;
    }
}
```